# Separar por mayúscula

Tags: r, regex

¿Alguien sabe la expresion regular en R para convertir esta frase

```
frase=CineCulturayentretenimientoPeriodismoPolíticaSociedadyDerechosHumanos
```

en esta?

```
Cine Cultura y entretenimiento Periodismo Política Sociedad y Derechos Humanos
```

Es decir, colocar un espacio delante y detrás de cada "Y" y meter un espacio detrás de cada letra mayúscula.

Tirando de mi lógica errónea pienso, primero localizo una "Y" y le pongo un espacio delante y detrás

```
gsub("y", "\\s\\y\\s",frase)
```

y ni eso saco.

Answer (score 3):

Es un patrón un poco ambiguo, ¿cuándo una `y` se usa como conjunción o forma parte de una palabra?, de cualquier manera, como tienes distintos patrones de reemplazo, vas a tener que aplicar varias veces `gsub()`:

```
frase <- 'CineCulturayentretenimientoPeriodismoPolíticaSociedadyDerechosHumanos'
# reemplazo de Mayúsculas por espacio + Mayúscula
frase <- gsub(pattern = '([[:upper:]])', x = frase, replacement = " \\1")
# reemplazo de la y entre dos minúsculas, este e el patrón ambiguo
frase <- gsub(pattern = '([[:lower:]])y([[:lower:]])', x = frase, replacement = "\\1 y \\2")
# reemplazo de la y +  Mayúscula
frase <- gsub(pattern = '([[:lower:]])y ', x = frase, replacement = "\\1 y ")

frase
[1] " Cine Cultura y entretenimiento Periodismo Política Sociedad y Derechos Humanos"
```

Answer (score 2):

Una alternativa que no es muy elegante, pero funciona:

```
library(tidyverse) # Porque prefiero el orden de argumento de stringr
str_split(frase, "(?<=.)(?=[A-Z])|(?<=.)(?=[y])|(?<=y)") %>% 
  .[[1]] %>%             #Porque str_split() regresa una lista y necesito un character vector, que es lo que está en la primera ubicación
  paste(collapse = " ")  #Porque tengo un character vector y lo que necesito es otro, pero de largo 1
```

El regex lo adapté de [este recurso](https://www.howtobuildsoftware.com/index.php/how-do/bom1/regex-r-dplyr-tidyr-split-camelcase-column-names). Lo importantes sería:

- `(?<=.)` es un lookbehind, "mira" que hay detrás, en este caso cualquier caracter.
- `(?=[A-Z])` es un lookahead, "mira" que hay delante, en este caso cualquier letra mayúscula. Con los dos combinados captura lo que hay entre otro caracter y una mayúscula y separa el CamelCase
- `|` es un operador el lógico o, captura también cuando se da la condición a la derecha.
- `(?<=.)(?=[y])` es igual al caso anterior, pero matchea antes del caracter `y` en lugar de mayúsculas
- `(?<=y)` matchea después del caracter `y`

Coincido con Patricio: es bastante ambigua la `y` porque podría estar en una palabra y separarla. Si conoces tus datos y sabes que no hay tal cosa podría seguro usarlo, aunque no generalizarlo. Si tienes algún caso de palabra con la letra `y` podría crear algún tipo de excepción en el regex. Ojalá no sea así.

Comment: tendría q mirar caso a caso a ver si hay alguna palabra con y, pero solo por curiosidad, ¿como se añade una excepcion? si por ejemplo aparece la palabra proyecto o inyectar

Comment: Soy muy rudimentario escribiendo expresiones regualares, así que haría lo de siempre: googlear hasta que aparezca la respuesta ;-) Un poquito más en serio: en regex hay un operador para negar, se podrían incluir palabras que sabes llevan la `y`. De todos modos creo que sería mejor buscar alguna alternativa a regex como toquenizar y usar un diccionario para reconstruir palabras (erroneamente) separadas. No es fácil, por eso lo de "ojalá no sea así".